# Tensorflow Object Detection API: Inference pre-trained Kitti Model on Cityscapes Data leads to low accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, inference, tfrecord

I am currently using the TF OD API. However, I run into some issues with the inference. 
Steps to Reproduce my issue:

- Download Faster R-CNN Resnet101 model pre-trained on Kitti Data
- Create Tf-Record files of some Cityscapes Data (first I extracted the bounding box coordinates and saved them to a txt file)
- Run inference of the pre-trained Resnet101-Kitti model on Kitti data (achieved accuracy ~90% mAP@0.5) and on Cityscapes data (achieved accuracy 0.000035% mAP@0.5) both on the classes pedestrian and car

I do not know why there is this large difference in the accuracy

I already used different image resolutions of the Cityscapes image data and I modified the original (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py) kitti_record file to look similar to the Cityscapes tfrecord file I create.

I use the tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md to create Cityscapes_tfrecord files and added only the difficult_obj attribute in order to not obtain an error.

I expect an accuracy of the inference on the Cityscapes data that is much higher. It should be over 10% or higher and not around 0.000035%.

Does anybody know why this error appears? I am struggling with this error since days and do not know how to solve it. 
Any remarks or hints are very appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: One method to address the isssue is to finetune the pretrained model on your Cityspaces dataset, this will give better performance on your dataset. You need to make a config file like this https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti.config

Comment: @danyfang Thanks for your remark. I already thought about the same. The accuracy will be lower when the pre-trained model is tested on another domain than the training data however, I expect an accuracy that is higher than 0.000035%. This is the point I do not understand.